# Android Camera API 2 incorrect camera characteristics

Tags: java, android

So I basically try to get highspeed FPS camera working in android.
I query android for the camera characteristics to determine if the camera is able to record high fps (120 -> 240) and in which resolution.

I use the Pixel2 virtual device which should support high FPS video mode yet the API doesn't return the correct  camera characteristics.

I tried to do the following:

```
// code to make sure that I got the backside cameraId here
CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);  
CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);  

StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics
               .get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
assert map != null;
mVideoSize = chooseVideoSize(map.getHighSpeedVideoSizes());
```

`map.getHighSpeedVideoSizes()` length is 0.

return of the `StreamConfigurationMap map`:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW3hz.jpg

I tried a different virtual device ( Pixel 2, Pixel 2XL) but I got the same output. I must be missing something here.

Comment: What does it return?

Comment: @tiagoperes `StreamConfigurationMap map` looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/Ak6otdl

Comment: Update your question with that information. In addition to that, In the end you say "it wasn't working as well". Does this mean you were getting the same error? By providing a more clear explanation of what you mean with it, the likelihood of someone being able to help you increases.